# Why isn't Pellet reasoner inferring subclass relationships?

Tags: owl, protege, pellet

I am just starting with Protégé and OWL. I just created a class hiearchy in Protege like:

```
:A rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ;
   owl:disjointWith :B .

:B rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing .

:C rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf :A ;
   owl:disjointWith :D .

:D rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf :A .

:E rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf :B .
```

When I start the pellet reasoner I expected for it to infer that all subclasses of A and B are also subclasses of Thing, which does not happen. Also I expected a SPARQL query `SELECT ?subject WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing}` would result in all classes A through B. However the query only returns A and B.

Am I doing something wrong or am I just not correct on what I expected?

Comment: Did you both select and start the reasoner? Those are two different menu options in Protégé.

Comment: It's possible the SPARQL query is not using the reasoner. I can't recall if there is any option that needs to be checked.

Comment: @Ignazio Yes, I selected Pellet and clicked start reasoner.

Comment: @Ignazio , already searched for any  options and didn't find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple SPARQL plugins in Protege. If you want to use reasoning, the **Snap SPARQL Query plugin** is the way to use. Note, that this is **not** the default SPARQL plugin that comes with the Protege distribution, but has to be installed explicitly (via the plugin manager this is pretty simple).